# How to change ASP.NET website to use Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net, oauth

Currently I have a very simple google authentication built-in from ASP.NET website wizard  using **`Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth`**

with just a single code line in AuthConfig.cs file

```
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddGoogle();
```

and now I get an error from google

```
OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain
```

The problem is that I don't know how to update the website to support the new authentication method, I got an api key from google, but the `OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddGoogle` does not support parameters like the function for Facebook or twitter authentication.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using OpenID2 in your code, the problem could occur because Google has disabled OpenID2 for new domains.

Comment: I use DotNet.OpenAuth